# How can I view the events by location in analytics?

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, dom-events, analytics

On my website I have given 3 events to track.

1. When users click a download button, I get a `download_button` event.
2. When the user click on the text on that same button I get a `label_button` event.
3. When a user clicks on the non-label part of that button (that is the space between the Download text and button) I get a `non_label_event`.

So till yesterday my `download_button = label_button + non_label_event` because every time a user clicks it is usually 2 events (One `download_button` and the next on either `label or non-label`.

But today when I checked the `label_button` part got 180 clicks within 2 hours but the `download_button` has only 30. So there has been an error from tracking the event.

So is there a way to know the location from the event that has happened? I know in real time I can view from where the user is and what event they have made. But after that can I view it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can add '`Page`' as secondary dimensions in `Behavior --> Events --> Top Events` (you can select here the `Event label` as primary dimension).

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue:

**Go to Audience > Geo > Location then selected secondary dimension as Event category.**

*You won't get it other way around, I mean Behaviour> Event > adding location as dimension.*

Comment: The page location in URL is the page not country. Anyway, if you want to get the country you can find it in Geo report.